# How to download COCO dataset images?

Tags: python

I am trying to download the COCO dataset images using the following COCO API command:

```
from pycocotools.coco import COCO
import requests
catIds = COCO.getCatIds(catNms=['person','dog', 'car'])
```

...but am getting the following error message. Any idea why this is happening?

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-42-9cc4e2f62a0e> in <module>
----> 1 catIds = COCO.getCatIds(catNms=['person','dog', 'car'])

TypeError: getCatIds() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

Previously, I configured pycocotools using [these instructions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DTNIo.png).

**EDIT:**

Still some strange error messages. Looking into code it seems as if there are no such categories as a 'person','dog' or 'car'. Why is it so?

**My code:**

```
a = COCO()  
catIds = a.getCatIds(catNms=['person','dog', 'car'])
```

**Received error message:**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-57400207fde1> in <module>
      1 a = COCO() # calling init
----> 2 catIds = a.getCatIds(catNms=['person','dog', 'car'])

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pycocotools\coco.py in getCatIds(self, catNms, supNms, catIds)
    171             cats = self.dataset['categories']
    172         else:
--> 173             cats = self.dataset['categories']
    174             cats = cats if len(catNms) == 0 else [cat for cat in cats if cat['name']          in catNms]
    175             cats = cats if len(supNms) == 0 else [cat for cat in cats if cat['supercategory'] in supNms]

KeyError: 'categories'
```

**Extract from the file 'cocoapi/PythonAPI/pycocotools/coco.py':**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

COCO is a python class and getCatIds is not a Static Method, tho can only be called by an instance/object of the Class COCO and not from the class itself.

You can probably solve it by doing this instead:

```
a = COCO() # calling init
catIds = a.getCatIds(catNms=['person','dog', 'car']) # calling the method from the class
```

(answer based on reading the code from https://github.com/cocodataset/cocoapi/blob/master/PythonAPI/pycocotools/coco.py)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the demo code [here](https://github.com/cocodataset/cocoapi/blob/master/PythonAPI/pycocoDemo.ipynb), you have to download the data separately then use the `pycocotools` package to access the data:

```py
from pycocotools.coco import COCO

# After downloading images from http://cocodataset.org/#download

# Define location of annotations
dataDir = '..'
dataType = 'val2017'
annFile = f'{dataDir}/annotations/instances_{dataType}.json'

# Create instance
coco = COCO(annFile)

# Filter for specific categories 
catIds = coco.getCatIds(catNms=['person','dog', 'car'])
```

Comment: Does this mean if I have already downloaded the zip file of all the images, this won't try to redownload the images?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai the point is you first download the json file from the cocodataset website which contains the image urls besides the relevant data related to the image and annotations. Then you use the annotations json file to download the actual images.